# Performance bottleneck when migrating large (millions) number of records in orientdb

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I am getting serious performance issues when migrating large number of nodes along with edges from another database (cassandra in my case) to orientdb.

Till 80 Mn of nodes and 100 MN of edges, speed was quite good at 1million per hour but now it has reduced drastically to 1 million in 16 hour. What can be the issue?

I am using standalone instance of orientdb with tomcat in embedded mode and doing document level api inserts using OMassiveInsert intent.

Comment: I'd need more information, like the indexes on that data, what kind? How many properties? How much heap and DISKCACHE memory? Etc.

Comment: I have one index each for node and edge. Node index is on primarykey unique_hash_index and edge index is on out,in unique. I have still 600 Mn more nodes and 900Mn links to be inserted. Once, it is live, It will be working on scale of 1 billion records.

Comment: 7 properties on node of which 1 is primary key index(string). rest 6 are strings. edge contain only 2 property i.e. out and in link. Tomcat heap is 8GB and DISKCACHE is 20 GB. Total RAM is 48 GB and HDD is production grade hard disk.

Comment: @Lvca, Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: We discovered some bottleneck with hash index. Could you please try to remove both indexes and try recreating as SBTREE (default)?

Comment: Link index is sbtree by default. I will remove node index and create sbtree index and let you know.

Comment: No use, performance is still bad as earlier.

Comment: (Following via email)

Comment: Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: hey @maveroid did you figure out what your problem was? I'm facing similar issues on loading my DB with billions of edges...